# Where do we get the transcation ID that we replace on the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to this Fragment theory and I can't seem to understand where we get the `R.id.container` So I want to start a fragment once a button is clicked. Here is my method

My main Method, I have not added any code to start my Fragment class.

```
 callCenter.setOnClickListener(view -> openCallCenter());

     //on clicked open call center which should start a fragment
        private void openCallCenter() {



        }
```

My Fragment Class: empty for now;

```
public class CallCenterFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = CallCenterFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    public CallCenterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call_center, container, false);
    }

}
```

My Fragment Layout Empty for now:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        tools:context=".fragment.CallCenterFragment">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

SO: my biggest question is on my mainActivity class what code should I add to start this fragment and can someone explain to me since I have seen several example where do we get `transaction.replace(R.id.container)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will refer you here for more details
On the container [Purpose of Container in Fragments for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714489/purpose-of-container-in-fragments-for-android)

And if you want to display your fragment on the Main activity as your question says try this code.

Add the code on the method.

```
CallCenterFragment fragment = new 
 CallCenterFragment();
 FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    trans.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    trans.commit();
```

Note. On your main xml you need to add the container id eg.

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/container"
  Add width and height />
```

You will display the text given on your fragment which is string hello blank fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ViewPager in activity xml file where you want show fragment. Create a sub class PageAdapter for super class for super class FragmentPagerAdapter. Complete abstract methods in Subclass.

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getI tem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:{
            fragment = new ContactFragment();
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            fragment = new RecentFragment();
            break;
        }
    }

    return fragment;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // 2 is no of fragments
    return 2;
}
}
```

Then After

```
//--write this code in base activity of fragment
contactview_f = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
contactview_f.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

Comment: so I can not just display it without an adapter? I just want to try to display the fragment with a text.

Comment: I just wanted to display it on my main without the adapter. :) thanks again.